# Edit Google Sheet data through editable html table

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to edit the google sheet data by html table, i have successfully updated the data in HTML table but not able to edit the same data in html table & google sheet.

Googlesheet data in HTMLoutput table is:

```
   function list(){
    var percentiles = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("Advance").getRange(2,3).getValues();
    var rawScores = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("Advance").getRange(2,4).getValues(); 
    var input = rawScores.indexOf(console);
    Logger.log(input); 
    function map(input) {   
      for (var i = 0; i <rawScores.length; i++) {
        if (rawScores[i] >= input) {
           return percentiles[i];
         }
       }
     } 
   }
```

Script is below which i used to update the HTMLtable:-

```
<script>   
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generate).getTable();

   });

   function generate(dataArray){
   var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");
   dataArray.forEach(function(r){
   var row =document.createElement("tr");
   var col1 =document.createElement("td");
   col1.textContent = r[0];
   var col2 =document.createElement("td");
   col2.textContent = r[1];
   var col3 =document.createElement("td");
   col3.textContent = r[2];
   var col4 =document.createElement("td");
   col4.textContent = r[3];
   var col5 =document.createElement("td");
   col5.textContent = r[4];
   var col6 =document.createElement("td");
   col6.textContent = r[5];
   var col7 =document.createElement("td");
   col7.textContent = r[6];
   var col8 =document.createElement("td");
   col8.textContent = r[7];
   var col9 =document.createElement("td");
   col9.textContent = r[8];
   var col10 =document.createElement("td");
   col10.textContent = r[9];

   row.appendChild(col1);
   row.appendChild(col2);
   row.appendChild(col3);
   row.appendChild(col4);
   row.appendChild(col5);
   row.appendChild(col6);
   row.appendChild(col7);
   row.appendChild(col8);
   row.appendChild(col9);
   row.appendChild(col10);
   tbody.appendChild(row);
   });
   }




</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

### A Google Sheets table can be updated only serverside, through an Apps Script function.

I assume you are using a Web App.

You can call an Apps Script function from the `HTML` file of your project with [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run).

Sample:

- Implement into the `HTML` file after defining your variable `dataArray`

```
<script>
  ...
  google.script.run.updateTable(dataArray);
  ...
</script>
```

- Create in the `.gs` part of your project a function `updateTable(dataArray)`, something like

```
function updateTable(dataArray){
  var myValues=[];
  myValues[0]=[];
  for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length;i++){
    myValues[0][i]=dataArray[i];
  }
  var myRow=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("MY SHEET").getRange("The Range Of My Row"); // e.g. getRange(1,1,1,10); to obtain the first 10 columns of the first row
  myRow.setValues(myValues);
}
```